# AWS RDS: specifying lc_collate and lc_ctype for PostgreSQL in cloud formation template

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL database on RDS using CloudFormation.How do I specify LC_COLLATE or LC_CTYPE in the template, those need to be set during database creation and cannot be changed afterward.

Right now both values will always be set to en_US.UTF-8.